# I am trying to import some text in a txt file but its not working

Tags: python

This is my code:

```py
file = open('C:/Users/SNEHIL RAJ/OneDrive/Desktop/shanu/coding/VS code workspace/python/gorcontent.txt', "w")
user_input = input("Type something\n")
file.write(user_input)
```

When I check my gorcontent folder it's completely blanked out.

Comment: try `"w+"` instead of `"w"`

Comment: also check if all the folders in your path exist

Comment: Try closing the file with `file.close` - some systems don’t properly write until the file is closed

Answer (score 1):

Its because you don't close the file, that's why its more efficient to use the with statement like this (with statement automatically closes the file):

```
with open('C:/Users/SNEHIL RAJ/OneDrive/.../python/gorcontent.txt', "w") as file:
  user_input = input("Type something\n")
  file.write(user_input)
```